# How to render text data as it is in React 16 using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

My end goal is to render text data of API as it is in React js.I have done so far is to integrating axios to get data.My challenge is as data I am fetching from URL is just a text.I cannot parse or fetch data as JSON.I am able to see the text response as text under browser network tab.I am not able to see it in front view.
How can I map and render all text data in React?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Grid, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
class About extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://terriblytinytales.com/test.txt"
      )
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.map(obj => obj.data);
        this.setState({ posts });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log((error));
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} md={6}>
            <h1>fetched data</h1>
            <ul>
              {this.state.posts.map((post, id) => <li key={id}>{post}</li>)}
            </ul>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
export default About;
```

Comment: are you seeing some issue while doing res.data.map  as it is just text?

Comment: yes TypeError: res.data.map is not a function . what i have to fix here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
class About extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://terriblytinytales.com/test.txt"
      )
      .then(res => {
        //console.log("res", res)
        const posts = res.data
        //debugger
        this.setState({ posts });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log((error));
      });
  }

  render() {
  //console.log(this.state.posts)
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div xs={12} md={6}>
            <h1>fetched data</h1>
            <ul dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.posts}}>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<About />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.32.0/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If you want to style rows separately , you have to parse the data or ask for response in JSON format

Comment: can you guide little bit for parsing the data?

Comment: also what is dangerouslySetInnerHTML ? it is fine to use in coding ?

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML is used to inject dynamic html into react renders. You can read more about it on react website. I am trying to parse the text point wise. Do you need it still

Comment: you can use following regex to parse it. posts.split(new RegExp(/[1-9]+\.\s/g)). ANd you will get separate rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163033/discussion-between-amar-ghodke-and-stack26).